# BFS solution to find least perfect squares

Tags: python

I am working on a [Perfect Squares - LeetCode](https://leetcode.com/problems/perfect-squares/)

> 279. Perfect Squares
>
> Given a positive integer *n*, find the least number of perfect square numbers (for example, `1, 4, 9, 16, ...`) which sum to *n*.
>
> **Example 1:**
>
> ```
> Input: n = 12
> Output: 3 
> Explanation: 12 = 4 + 4 + 4.
> ```
>
> **Example 2:**
>
> ```
> Input: n = 13
> Output: 2
> Explanation: 13 = 4 + 9.
> ```

The key idea convert it to a find shortest path from n to 0 in a graph

[image]

A standard DFS solution

```
class Solution:
    def numSquares(self, n):
        """
        :type n: int
        :rtype: int
        """
        from collections import deque 
        #declare
        queue = deque()
        visited = set()
        #intitiate 
        step = -1
        queue.append(n)
        visited.add(n)

        while queue:
            step += 1
            size = len(queue)  

            for _ in range(size):
                cur = queue.popleft()
                if cur == 0: return step  #terminating checking 

                #strech to collect next nodes 
                i = 1
                next_ = cur - i**2 #
                while next_ >= 0:
                    if next_ not in visited:
                        queue.append(next_)
                        visited.add(next_)

                    i += 1
                    next_  = cur - i**2
```

> Runtime: 2532 ms, faster than 40.71% of Python3 online submissions for Perfect Squares.
>   Memory Usage: 14 MB, less than 18.25% of Python3 online submissions for Perfect Squares.

The part to collect next nodes  is not very concise

```
                #strech to collect next nodes 
                i = 1
                next_ = cur - i**2 #
                while next_ >= 0:
                    if next_ not in visited:
                        queue.append(next_)
                        visited.add(next_)

                    i += 1
                    next_  = cur - i**2
```

Tried to revise it as

```
            i = 1                  
            while  cur - i** 2 >= 0:
                next_ = cur - i ** 2:
                if next_ not in visited:
                    queue.append(next_)
                    visited.add(next_)
                i += 1
```

It worked but exceeded the time limitation.

How could refactor that part?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the reason of `TLE` is you do `cur - i** 2` twice, `square` is costy here. I change to `cur - i * i`, it pass.

In most situation, double the calculation will not cause `TLE`, but `DFS` here is slow enough(cost `2560ms` in my test), so it cares.

If you don't want to assign `next_` twice, and python not support grammar assignment in comparison, like this:

```
while (next_ = cur - i**2) >= 0:
```

so you can try this (which I think is also ugly):

```
i = 1
while True:
    next_ = cur - i ** 2
    if next_ < 0:
        break

    if next_ not in visited:
        queue.append(next_)
        visited.add(next_)
    i += 1
```

By the way, I just noticed it has nothing to do with `BFS`, and `BFS` is the faster solution to solve this problem.